# Angular is improperly scoping isolate directives with server rendered content

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a web application that uses angular on top of server rendered HTML.

I am trying to use a piece of the rendered HTML as a reusable component (directive), so I attach an attribute directive on the appropriate tag in the HTML that is returned. This directive needs to have an isolated scope, and it will further include child directives that should be child scopes within this isolated directive.

Unfortunately, angular is not creating the directives from the returned HTML with the proper scope hierarchy. The child directives within the isolated scope are siblings of the isolated scope (instead of children). Now, if I change these directives to use client-side templates, it works correctly. So it seems as though angular does not like constructing directives of this form from server generated HTML.

To better illustrate my problem, I created a couple plunkers - one that works correctly (client side templates), and one that works incorrectly (server rendered HTML).

[Server Rendered Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aD1ImdOdlbDN31i45yBw?p=preview)

index.html

```
<body>
  <div isolate-dir>
    Content from the server
    <div child-dir>
      More content from the server: <span ng-bind="testVar">server data</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('test', []);

angular.module('test').directive('isolateDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      console.log('isolate dir scope [' + scope.$id + ' -> ' + scope.$parent.$id + ']');
    }
  }
});

angular.module('test').directive('childDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      console.log('child dir scope [' + scope.$id + ' -> ' + scope.$parent.$id + ']');
      scope.testVar = "client data";
    }
  }
});
```

output

```
child dir scope [3 -> 1]
isolate dir scope [2 -> 1]
```

[Client Templating Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rbis2Uj6p1QRF7a1Rl80?p=preview)

index.html

```
<body>
  <div isolate-dir></div>
</body>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('test', []);

angular.module('test').directive('isolateDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      console.log('isolate dir scope [' + scope.$id + ' -> ' + scope.$parent.$id + ']');
    },
    template: "Content from the server <div child-dir></div>"
  }
});

angular.module('test').directive('childDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      console.log('child dir scope [' + scope.$id + ' -> ' + scope.$parent.$id + ']');
      scope.testVar = "client data";
    },
    template: "More content from the server: <span ng-bind='testVar'>server data</span>"
  }
});
```

output

```
child dir scope [3 -> 2]
isolate dir scope [2 -> 1]
```

When the plunkers are run and the console output is observed, you can see that the scope hierarchy is correct in the client templated version and incorrect in the server rendered version.

**Why is the scope hierarchy incorrect with server rendered content, and what is the best way to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is this has nothing to do with "server" rendering or not.

The problem comes from your understanding of directives. The isolated directive (`isolate-dir`) will indeed have an isolated scope which affects its template and controller. However the HTML hierarchy has no relation with the Angular scoping hierarchy: only the `<div isolate-dir>` will have an isolated scope, but **not all of its children elements**.

If you want the children elements to inheritate from the scope of that parent `div`, you should either put these children into the isolated directive's template (which is done in your first example, hence it works), or propagate the parent scope to its inner elements using the `transclusion` parameter given to the `link` function.

Here is a plunkr using this method:

[plnkr.co/edit/n0ws7pPqOS8dt6IMKYMl?p=info](http://plnkr.co/edit/n0ws7pPqOS8dt6IMKYMl?p=info)

If that still confuses you, you can read more about it for instance here:

http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure I entirely understand how `transclusion` relates to this particular scenario since I'm not building a transcluded directive. It's essentially a typical directive - just already "pre-filled" by the server. And unfortunately, I don't have a choice but to use server-rendered content for this app. Either way, I tried locally to fix it by using the transclusion parameter to no avail (and I referenced the linked article). Do you mind giving an example of how to fix the server rendered version of the plunker, without using templates?

Comment: That's the point: if you don't use transclusion, the inner HTML will not inherit its scope from the directive. If you want to do that you *need* to use transclusion. Check that fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/n0ws7pPqOS8dt6IMKYMl?p=info

Comment: I see now. Thanks for the clarification and example.